# jQuery: stretch text area like Chrome does

Tags: jquery, resizable

Is there a plugin that would allow me to convert plain textarea to a stretchable one, just like Chrome does.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the [Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#textarea) plugin?

Comment: This works very well. The other alternative is to do a facebook-style (self.shudder()) textarea that grows as needed.

Comment: Can't get the textarea to resize at all with this plugin. Div around it grows but text area does not.

Answer (score 2):

See http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#textarea

There's also [TextAreaResizer](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextAreaResizer), but the demos only show vertical resizing so I'm not sure if it supports diagonal resizing.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin called [TextAreaResizer](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextAreaResizer), see if it offers everything you're looking for.

It's only vertical, but it's the most cross-browser stable thing I've seen.  [Here's a link right to the demo](http://www.itsavesyou.com/TextArea_Resizer_example.htm)